# Variable from url string is empty?

Tags: php

I have a problem to get variable from url string, variable is always empty when I test it. I can't find problem in my code. Can you help me ? Thank you very much

URL strings example:

```
$url_seznam: http://search.seznam.cz/?q=%c5%a1kolen%c3%ad+mistr%c5%af+ve+v%c3%bdrob%c4%9b&sourceid=szn-hp&sgid=qaqnqapauacxumty6e9thnwokswozilikiqbygqjkq%3d%3d&oq=%c5%a1kolen%c3%ad+mistr%c5%af+ve+v%c3%bdrob%c4%9b&aq=-1&thru=&su=e

$url_bing: http://www.bing.com/search?q=scada+academy&go=Odeslat&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=scada+academy&sc=2-13&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=6c8f027c29a5422a931277ccfc1ddc35
```

PHP:

```
if(strpos($_SESSION['ref'], 'seznam.cz')){
    $url_seznam = $_SESSION['ref'];
    $url_seznam1 = parse_url($url_seznam);
    $query = array();
    parse_str($url['query'], $query);
    $ref_word = $query['q'];
    $ref_addr = "Seznam Vyhledávač - ";
    $ref_word = str_replace('+',' ',$ref_word);
    $ref_word = utf8_decode(urldecode("$ref_word"));
    $ref_addr .= "$ref_word";
    $_SESSION['ref'] = $ref_addr;
}
if(strpos($_SESSION['ref'], 'bing.com')){
    $url_bing = $_SESSION['ref'];
    $url_bing1 = parse_url($url_bing);
    $query = array();
    parse_str($url['query'], $query);
    $ref_word = $query['q'];
    $ref_addr = "Bing Search - ";
    $ref_word = str_replace('+',' ',$ref_word);
    $ref_word = utf8_decode(urldecode("$ref_word"));
    $ref_addr .= "$ref_word";
    $_SESSION['ref'] = $ref_addr;
}

echo "$_SESSION[ref]"; // When I searched with Bing: Bing Search - or with Seznam: Seznam Vyhledávač -
// It should be Bing Search - or Seznam Vyhledávač - value of 'q' variable from URL string
```

Comment: `echo "SESSION[ref]"` isn't echoing out a variable. there's no `$`. That's just a string. Perhaps you want `echo $_SESSION['ref']`?

Comment: Perhaps neither condition is met. But in any case `echo $_SESSION['ref'];`

Comment: Yeah of course $_SESSION[ref] sry I am blind :)

Comment: still missing the apostrophes around `'ref'` ...

Comment: @SO because variable is inside ""

Comment: @user3105439 fair play, didn't see the quotes :)

Comment: How do you develop? Debug by print can only take you so far. Get a decent IDE (like NetBeans, Eclipse,etc) and use the debugger. Set a breakpoint & run to it, step through your code to see which logic is executed, examine variables, etc

Comment: @Mawg Thank you very much. You helps me a lot :( I use PHPdesigner and Its great IDE.

Comment: @Mawg Problem solved it should be variable $url_seznam1 or $url_bing1 insted of $url inside parse_str function